# Cannot execute file when FILE_READ permission is removed on Windows 7 or newer

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

Windows is a secure operating system, and has a rich infrastructure of access checks. Two of those [*file access rights*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants) of interest right now are:

- `FILE_READ_DATA` (1): *"For a file object, the right to read the corresponding file data."*
- `FILE_EXECUTE` (32): *"For a native code file, the right to execute the file."*

The virtue of a separate `FILE_EXECUTE` right is:

- it lets the user **execute** the file
- without being able to **see** what's in the file

It lets you keep the application binary contents secret. It prevents the file from being copied.

### It worked pre-Windows 7

This is how it worked on Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Vista:

- You could grant all access rights (including `FILE_EXECUTE`)
- but *exclude* `FILE_READ_DATA`:

[image]

And the user can *"execute"* a file they cannot *"read"*:

**Windows 2000**: they can execute a file they cannot read

[image]

**Windows XP**: they can execute a file they cannot read

[image]

**Windows Vista**: they can execute a file they cannot read

[image]

## Until Windows 7

That all worked great until Windows 7; where the file cannot be executed:

[image]

Looking at the stack trace of the function that gets the `ACCESS_DENIED` result, it's **CreateProcess** itself that is attempting to *"read"* the file:

```
0   fltmgr.sys      FltpPerformPreCallbacks + 0x361 0x82fabdf7  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
1   fltmgr.sys      FltpPassThroughInternal + 0x40  0x82faed38  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
2   fltmgr.sys      FltpCreateInternal + 0x24   0x82fc2256  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
3   fltmgr.sys      FltpCreate + 0x2c9  0x82fc291b  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
4   ntkrnlpa.exe    IofCallDriver + 0x63    0x8283ff22  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
5   ntkrnlpa.exe    IopParseDevice + 0xf08  0x82a5ae83  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
6   ntkrnlpa.exe    ObpLookupObjectName + 0x510 0x82a3a080  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
7   ntkrnlpa.exe    ObOpenObjectByName + 0x165  0x82a4a72c  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
8   ntkrnlpa.exe    IopCreateFile + 0x6c3   0x82a4100a  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
9   ntkrnlpa.exe    NtOpenFile + 0x2a   0x82a473a2  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
10  ntkrnlpa.exe    KiSystemServicePostCall 0x82846a3a  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
11  ntkrnlpa.exe    ZwOpenFile + 0x11   0x828449c5  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
12  ntkrnlpa.exe    KiSystemServicePostCall 0x82846a3a  C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
13  ntdll.dll       ZwCreateUserProcess + 0xc   0x7738526c  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
14  kernel32.dll    CreateProcessInternalW + 0xe81  0x76421133  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
```

> **`15 kernel32.dll    CreateProcessW + 0x2c   0x763d2079  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll`**

```
17  SHELL32.dll     CExecuteApplication::_CreateProcess + 0xfc  0x76712b92  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
18  SHELL32.dll     CExecuteApplication::_TryCreateProcess + 0x2e   0x76705399  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
19  SHELL32.dll     CExecuteAssociation::_DoCommand + 0x88  0x7671f5e1  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
20  SHELL32.dll     CExecuteAssociation::_TryApplication + 0x41 0x767049e4  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
21  SHELL32.dll     CExecuteAssociation::Execute + 0x5f 0x7671f663  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
22  SHELL32.dll     CRegDataDrivenCommand::_Invoke + 0xe2   0x76720f21  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
23  SHELL32.dll     CRegDataDrivenCommand::InvokeFromContextMenu + 0x18 0x76720e52  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
24  SHELL32.dll     CRegistryVerbsContextMenu::_Execute + 0x5a  0x767210a5  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
25  SHELL32.dll     CRegistryVerbsContextMenu::InvokeCommand + 0xa4 0x76721008  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
26  SHELL32.dll     HDXA_LetHandlerProcessCommandEx + 0x132 0x7672049c  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
27  SHELL32.dll     CDefFolderMenu::InvokeCommand + 0x1ca   0x76720374  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
28  SHELL32.dll     SHInvokeCommandOnContextMenu2 + 0x1cd   0x76a716c5  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
29  SHELL32.dll     s_DoInvokeVerb + 0x9d   0x76a71924  C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
30  SHLWAPI.dll     WrapperThreadProc + 0x1b5   0x75aa43c0  C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
31  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xe   0x7641ef3c  C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
32  ntdll.dll       __RtlUserThreadStart + 0x70 0x773a360c  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
33  ntdll.dll       _RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1b  0x773a35df  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

I assume this must be related to the heuristics of **CreateProcess** with the invention of UAC - but i don't see why it working on Windows Vista (where UAC was first invented).

> Bonus video: [Channel 9, Going https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/UAC-What-How-Why](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/UAC-What-How-Why)

### How to make it work?

So the question is:

- how do i let users execute an application
- while also not granting `FILE_READ_DATA`

?

## Bonus Research

### Only fails with embedded assembly manifest

It only fails when the executable has an embedded assembly manifest. It doesn't matter if the manifest is empty (e.g. no dependancy on any dll, no dpi awareness, no app compat - empty). (Note: every correctly written application must have an assembly manifest; it's part of the ABI contract with Windows)

### ShellExecute and CreateProcess fail alike

Calling `CreateProcess` myself directly (as opposed to the higher level `ShellExecute` abstraction) still has the error:

```
0   FLTMGR.SYS           FltDecodeParameters + 0x1cfc                
1   FLTMGR.SYS           FltDecodeParameters + 0x1840                
2   FLTMGR.SYS           FltQueryInformationFile + 0x963             
3   ntoskrnl.exe         IofCallDriver + 0x59                        
4   ntoskrnl.exe         KeInitializeEvent + 0x64                    
5   ntoskrnl.exe         SeSetAccessStateGenericMapping + 0x81b      
6   ntoskrnl.exe         SeUnlockSubjectContext + 0x85f              
7   ntoskrnl.exe         ObOpenObjectByNameEx + 0x201                
8   ntoskrnl.exe         NtCreateFile + 0x8b0                        
9   ntoskrnl.exe         IoCreateFileEx + 0x11d                      
10  ntoskrnl.exe         IoCreateFile + 0x52c                        
11  ntoskrnl.exe         setjmpex + 0x7bd8                           
12  ntdll.dll            NtCreateUserProcess + 0x14                  
13  wow64.dll            Wow64IsStackExtentsCheckEnforced + 0x1098   
14  wow64.dll            Wow64IsStackExtentsCheckEnforced + 0x880    
15  wow64.dll            Wow64SystemServiceEx + 0x153                
16  wow64cpu.dll         TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd + 0xb           
17  wow64cpu.dll         BTCpuSimulate + 0x9                         
18  wow64.dll            Wow64LdrpInitialize + 0x26a                 
19  wow64.dll            Wow64LdrpInitialize + 0x127                 
20  ntdll.dll            LdrInitShimEngineDynamic + 0x3133           
21  ntdll.dll            memset + 0x1edf5          
22  ntdll.dll            LdrInitializeThunk + 0x63                   
23  ntdll.dll            LdrInitializeThunk + 0xe                    
24  ntdll.dll            NtCreateUserProcess + 0xc                   
25  KernelBase.dll       CreateProcessInternalW + 0x19db             
26  KernelBase.dll       CreateProcessInternalA + 0x272              
27  KernelBase.dll       CreateProcessA + 0x2c                       
28  TestFileExecute.exe  TestFileExecute.exe + 0xd3b31
```

### Bonus Reading

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/cannot-execute-file-when-fileread-permission-is/038c6621-538a-4233-8bb9-ade5ba9c7e98

Comment: I know these sound like stupid questions but.. have you tried calling CreateProcess() on a native application vs .net application?  Are you calling CreateProcess() from your code or relying on the shell to do it?  I 100% do not have the answer to this.. but you have me intrigued.. hrrrmmm.... And my guess.. either someone in MS that didn't know better "Fixed it".. or there was a security flaw having to do with the way CreateProcess maps exes into memory.

Comment: I'm only launching it from Explorer (which calls `ShellExecute`); and it's a native (i.e. not .NET) application.

Comment: They can't leave the explorer alone.  Half of my hand-written shell extensions no longer function and many of the things the explorer did pre-win7 were cut from the code.  I am betting they changed any of the billion flags for calling CreateProcess().  If it were me, I would play with a stand-alone test to call CreateProcess() to see if the problem is actually there.  If not, you might be able to make a shim between the explorer and your app that needs to remain hidden.. ?? :^P ..  Just guessing and trying to help.